# How can I uninstall Moodle on Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, moodle

I tried uninstalling Moodle on Ubuntu by running the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove moodle
```

but the result I got was:

```
package moodle is not installed, so not removed
```

but I'm still able to access it.

I want to try out a fresh moodle installation.

Comment: How did you install moodle?

Comment: A former colleague installed it for me some years ago.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do to remove moodle is to delete its code directory, data directory and database.

In the`config.php` you will find variable `$CFG->dbtype` that says what database engine is used with that installation and variable `$CFG->dbname` will tell you which database you should remove.

In the same `config.php` you will also find where data is configured and where is the code path set - variables to check are: `$CFG->dataroot` and `$CFG->dirroot`.
If you have absolutely no idea where to look for moodle installation, you have to check it in your apache/nginx (or other http server) configuration.

But to test a fresh moodle installation you don't have to remove the old one - you can install a fresh one next to the old one, configure it properly, create a new database for the fresh installation and configure your http server to point to that installation.

It is advisable not to install moodle from any distribution's repository but to take it from moodle's git, choosing the right branch according to the version of moodle you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling looks pretty straightforward:  These directions were copied directly from [the moodle website](https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/Installation_FAQ#How_do_I_uninstall_Moodle.3F)

```
**Webhost/manual installation:** If you have installed Moodle manually or have installed onto a webhost, follow these steps:

Delete the moodle database using this mysql command (or delete using your mysql client, e.g. PHPMyAdmin):

    sql>DROP DATABASE moodle;

In the above example replace 'moodle' with the name of the moodle database you created when installing.

Delete the moodledata directory. If you, or your users, have uploaded materials into this directory take a copy of these before deleting this directory.

Delete the moodle directory itself. This will delete all of the moodle PHP script files.

**XAMPP windows installation:** If you have installed Moodle on windows through the XAMPP package, follow these steps:

Open cmd.exe and navigate to this directory within your installation directory:

    server/mysql/bin

Run this command, replacing USERNAME with your database username (the default is "root") and DATABASE with your database name (the default is "moodle"):

    mysqladmin.exe -u USERNAME -p drop DATABASE

Enter your database password at the prompt (the default is "" [blank]).

Enter "y" to confirm the database drop.

Delete the moodledata directory. If you, or your users, have uploaded materials into this directory take a copy of these before deleting this directory.

Delete the moodle directory itself. This will delete all of the moodle PHP script files
```

Answer (score 0):

on your terminal : `sudo /opt/lampp/apps/moodle/uninstall`